# Display selected items by category in Laravel Blade PDF view

Tags: laravel, pdf

I'm working on a Laravel project where users can select items from different categories, and I need to display the selected items in a PDF generated using Laravel Blade. I have categories like Living Room, Bedding, Kitchen, etc., and users can choose items from these categories.

Here is how the user can selected categories and how it is stored

```
       $bathQuantities = $_POST['bathitems'];
       $itemNames =[];

       // retrive all items from the database

       $items = DB::table('bath') -> get();

       // the following code creates an array to store the item names

       foreach ($items as $item) {

        $itemNames[$item->id] = $item -> bath_item;
       }

       $outputs = []; // this array will hold the output for each item


      

         // Insert the selected items into the requestorder table
                  $bathrequestOrder =[
                 'family_id' => $familyId, 
                  'category' => 'BATH', // set the requested item type
                'categoryTotal' => array_sum($bathQuantities), // set the total amount needed
                'daterequested' =>  now()  // set the current date and time
              ];


       foreach($bathQuantities as $id => $quantity) {
        
        if($quantity >0){

            // using optional object operator to avoid errors

            $item = DB::table('bath') ->where('id',$id)->first();
            
            if($item){

                $itemName = $item->bath_item;
                DB::table('requestorder')->insert([
                    'family_id' => $familyId,
                    'category' => 'BATH',
                    'categoryTotal' => array_sum($bathQuantities),
                  'requestedItem' => $itemName,
                  'amountNeeded' => $quantity,
                  'daterequested' =>  now() 
                ]);




             $output = $item ->bath_item. ':'.$quantity;
             $outputs[] = $output; // append the output to the array
            }
        }
  

       }

       $outputString = implode(', ', $outputs); // Join the outputs into a single string
//dd($outputString);
       
       
       // condition if any item from living room category was selected 
       
       $livingroomQuantities = $_POST['livingroomitems'];
       
    
       $livingroomItemsNames =[];
       
       //retrive all items from table for livingroom category
       $livingroomItems = DB::table('livingroom') -> get();
       
       // create an array to store the items
       
       foreach($livingroomItems as $livingroomItem) {
           $livingroomItemsNames[$livingroomItem -> id] = $livingroomItem -> livingroom_item;
       }
       
       $livingroomOutputs =[]; // this array will hold the output for each item
       
       $livingroomrequestOrder = [
          'family_id' => $familyId, 
  'category' => 'LIVINGROOM', // set the requested item type
  'categoryTotal' => array_sum($livingroomQuantities), // set the total amount needed
  'daterequested' =>  now()  // set the current date and time 
       ];
       
       
       foreach($livingroomQuantities as $id => $livingRoomQuantity) {
           if ($livingRoomQuantity > 0) {
               
               $livingroomItem = DB::table('livingroom') -> where('id',$id)->first();
               
               if( $livingroomItem) {
                   
                    $livingroomItemsName = $livingroomItem -> livingroom_item;
                    DB::table('requestorder') -> insert([
                  'family_id' => $familyId,
                  'category' => 'LIVINGROOM',
                  'categoryTotal' => array_sum($livingroomQuantities),
                  
                  'requestedItem' => $livingroomItemsName,
                  'amountNeeded' => $livingRoomQuantity,
                  'daterequested' =>  now() 
                    ]);
                    
                 
                    $livingroomOutput = $livingroomItem -> livingroom_item. ':' .$livingRoomQuantity;
                    $livingroomOutputs[] =$livingroomOutput; //append the output to the array 
               }
           }
       }
       
       $livingroomOutputString = implode( $livingroomOutputs);
       
       
       // condition if any item from bedding category was selected 
      
       $beddingQuantities = $_POST['beddingitems'];
      // dd($beddingQuantities);
       $beddingItemsNames =[];
       
       //retrive all items from table for livingroom category
       $beddingItems = DB::table('bedding') -> get();
       
       // create an array to store the items
       
       foreach($beddingItems as $beddingItem) {
           $beddingItemsNames[$beddingItem -> id] = $beddingItem -> bedding_item;
       }
       
       $beddingOutputs =[]; // this array will hold the output for each item
       
       $beddingrequestOrder = [
          'family_id' => $familyId, 
  'category' => 'BEDDING', // set the requested item type
  'categoryTotal' => array_sum($beddingQuantities), // set the total amount needed
  'daterequested' =>  now()  // set the current date and time 
       ];
       
       
       foreach($beddingQuantities as $id => $beddingQuantity) {
           if ($beddingQuantity > 0) {
               
               $beddingItem = DB::table('bedding') -> where('id',$id)->first();
               
               if( $beddingItem) {
                   
                    $beddingItemsName = $beddingItem -> bedding_item;
                    DB::table('requestorder') -> insert([
                  'family_id' => $familyId,
                  'category' => 'BEDDING',
                  'categoryTotal' => array_sum($beddingQuantities),
                  
                  'requestedItem' => $beddingItemsName,
                  'amountNeeded' => $beddingQuantity,
                  'daterequested' =>  now() 
                    ]);
                    
                 
                    $beddingOutput = $beddingItem -> bedding_item. ':' .$beddingQuantity;
                    $beddingOutputs[] =$beddingOutput; //append the output to the array 
               }
           }
       }
       
       $beddingOutputString = implode( $beddingOutputs); 
      
       // condition if any item from bedroom category was selected 
       
       $bedroomQuantities = $_POST['bedroomitems'];
     
       $bedroomItemsNames =[];
       
       //retrive all items from table for livingroom category
       $bedroomItems = DB::table('bedroom') -> get();
       
       // create an array to store the items
       
       foreach($bedroomItems as $bedroomItem) {
           $bedroomItemsNames[$bedroomItem -> id] = $bedroomItem -> bedroom_item;
       }
       
       $bedroomOutputs =[]; // this array will hold the output for each item
       
       $bedroomrequestOrder = [
          'family_id' => $familyId, 
  'category' => 'BEDROOM', // set the requested item type
  'categoryTotal' => array_sum($bedroomQuantities), // set the total amount needed
  'daterequested' =>  now()  // set the current date and time 
       ];
       
       
       foreach($bedroomQuantities as $id => $bedroomQuantity) {
           if ($bedroomQuantity > 0) {
               
               $bedroomItem = DB::table('bedroom') -> where('id',$id)->first();
               
               if( $bedroomItem) {
                   
                    $bedroomItemsName = $bedroomItem -> bedroom_item;
                    DB::table('requestorder') -> insert([
                  'family_id' => $familyId,
                  'category' => 'BEDROOM',
                  'categoryTotal' => array_sum($bedroomQuantities),
                  
                  'requestedItem' => $bedroomItemsName,
                  'amountNeeded' => $bedroomQuantity,
                  'daterequested' =>  now() 
                    ]);
                    
                 
                    $bedroomOutput = $bedroomItem -> bedroom_item. ':' .$bedroomQuantity;
                    $bedroomOutputs[] =$bedroomOutput; //append the output to the array 
               }
           }
       }
       
       $bedroomOutputString = implode( $bedroomOutputs);
       
      
   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       
       $kitchenQuantities = $_POST['kichenitems'];
           //dd('kitchen stuff',$kitchenQuantities);
       $kitchenItemsNames =[];
       
       //retrive all items from table for livingroom category
       $kitchenItems = DB::table('kitchen') -> get();
       
       // create an array to store the items
       
       foreach($kitchenItems as $kitchenItem) {
           $kitchenItemsNames[$kitchenItem -> id] = $kitchenItem -> kitchen_item;
       }
       
       $kitchenOutputs =[]; // this array will hold the output for each item
       
       $kitchenrequestOrder = [
          'family_id' => $familyId, 
  'category' => 'KITCHEN', // set the requested item type
  'categoryTotal' => array_sum($kitchenQuantities), // set the total amount needed
  'daterequested' =>  now()  // set the current date and time 
       ];
       
       
       foreach($kitchenQuantities as $id => $kitchenQuantity) {
           if ($kitchenQuantity > 0) {
               
               $kitchenItem = DB::table('kitchen') -> where('id',$id)->first();
               
               if( $kitchenItem) {
                   
                    $kitchenItemsName = $kitchenItem -> kitchen_item;
                    DB::table('requestorder') -> insert([
                  'family_id' => $familyId,
                  'category' => 'KITCHEN',
                  'categoryTotal' => array_sum($kitchenQuantities),
                  
                  'requestedItem' => $kitchenItemsName,
                  'amountNeeded' => $kitchenQuantity,
                  'daterequested' =>  now() 
                    ]);
                    
                 
                    $kitchenOutput = $kitchenItem -> kitchen_item. ':' .$kitchenQuantity;
                    $kitchenOutputs[] =$kitchenOutput; //append the output to the array 
               }
           }
       }
       
   

        $kitchenOutputString = implode( $kitchenOutputs);
           ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
           
      // condition if any item from MISC category was selected 
           
           $miscellaneousQuantities = $_POST['miscsitems'];
           $miscellaneousItemsNames =[];
           
           
           $miscellaneousItems = DB::table('miscellaneous') -> get();
           
           // create an array to store the items
           
           foreach($miscellaneousItems as $miscellaneousItem) {
               $miscellaneousItemsNames[$miscellaneousItem -> id] = $miscellaneousItem -> misc_item;
           }
           
           $miscellaneousOutputs =[]; // this array will hold the output for each item
           
           $miscrequestOrder = [
              'family_id' => $familyId, 
      'category' => 'MISC', // set the requested item type
      'categoryTotal' => array_sum($miscellaneousQuantities), // set the total amount needed
      'daterequested' =>  now()  // set the current date and time 
           ];
           
           
           foreach($miscellaneousQuantities as $id => $miscellaneousQuantity) {
               if ($miscellaneousQuantity > 0) {
                   
                   $miscellaneousItem = DB::table('miscellaneous') -> where('id',$id)->first();
                   
                   if( $miscellaneousItem) {
                       
                        $miscellaneousItemsName = $miscellaneousItem -> misc_item;
                        DB::table('requestorder') -> insert([
                      'family_id' => $familyId,
                      'category' => 'MISC',
                      'categoryTotal' => array_sum($miscellaneousQuantities),
                      
                      'requestedItem' => $miscellaneousItemsName,
                      'amountNeeded' => $miscellaneousQuantity,
                      'daterequested' =>  now() 
                        ]);
                        
                     
                        $miscellaneousOutput = $miscellaneousItem -> misc_item. ':' .$miscellaneousQuantity;
                        $miscellaneousOutputs[] =$miscellaneousOutput; //append the output to the array 
                   }
               }
           }
           
           $miscellaneousOutputString = implode( $miscellaneousOutputs);
           ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// /
           
      // ***** condition if any item from BABY category was selected *****
           
           $babyQuantities = $_POST['babyitems'] ??[];
           
           $categoryTotal = array_sum($babyQuantities);
           
          // dd("baby quantities:" ,$babyQuantities, "Category Total:", $categoryTotal);
           $babyItems = DB::table('baby')
                   ->whereIn('id',array_keys($babyQuantities)) // get the requested items
                   ->get();
           $babyOutputs =[]; // this array will hold the output for each item
           
           
           
           foreach($babyQuantities as $id => $babyQuantity) {
               if ($babyQuantity > 0) {
                   
                   $babyItem = $babyItems -> where('id',$id)->first();
                   
                   if( $babyItem) {
                       
                        $babyItemsName = $babyItem -> baby_item;
                        DB::table('requestorder') -> insert([
                      'family_id' => $familyId,
                      'category' => 'BABY',
                            
                      'categoryTotal' => array_sum($babyQuantities),
                      
                      'requestedItem' => $babyItemsName,
                      'amountNeeded' => $babyQuantity,
                      'daterequested' =>  now() 
                        ]);
                        
                     
                        $babyOutput = $babyItem -> baby_item. ':' .$babyQuantity;
                        $babyOutputs[] =$babyOutput; //append the output to the array 
                   }
               }
           }
           
            
           
           $babyOutputString = implode( $babyOutputs);
    
    Here's how I'm currently attempting to display the selected items:
    
      
    
        
     $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf_layout', [
    
        
        'livingroomOutputString' => $livingroomOutputString ? 'Living Room: ' . $livingroomOutputString : '',
        'beddingOutputString' => $beddingOutputString ? 'Bedding: ' . $beddingOutputString : '',
        'bedroomOutputString' => $bedroomOutputString ? 'Bedroom: ' . $bedroomOutputString : '',
        'kitchenOutputString' => $kitchenOutputString ? 'Kitchen: ' . $kitchenOutputString : '',
        'miscellaneousOutputString' => $miscellaneousOutputString ? 'Miscellaneous: ' . $miscellaneousOutputString : '',
        'babyOutputString' => $babyOutputString ? 'Baby: ' . $babyOutputString : '',
    
    
     ]); 
    
     $pdfdata = $pdf ->output();
    
    
    <!-- pdf-layout.blade.php -->
    
    
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>CATEGORY</th>
                <th>ITEM</th>
                <th>NEED</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
             @foreach($selectedCategories as $category => $items)
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="{{ count($items) }}">{{ $category }}</td>
                @foreach($items as $item)
                <td>{{ $item['name'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item['quantity'] }}</td>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    
    </table>
```

what is the best approach to solve this?